# how to repeat table header in a new page-break

Tags: php, html, css, google-chrome

I have a dynamic table in my web page that sometimes contains lots of rows. I made the page-break after 22 rows. i need to repeat certain table (info table, see image) in a new page. how do i do that?

image
https://i.ibb.co/LN8gVbD/Screen-Shot-2019-05-26-at-03-34-26.png

the other thing, I'm unable to get the page-break in Chrome. it's only working in Firefox, how to fix that in Chrome?

```
 <style type="text/css">
    #receipt-data { font-size: 12px; }
        @media print {
                tr.page-break{
                page-break-inside: avoid;;
                page-break-before:always; 
            }  
            @page {
              size:portrait;
                }
        }
    </style>

    <div id="receipt-data">
<table class="table hed">
<thead style="text-align:center;">
<tr style="text-align:center;">  
    <th colspan="1">Name</th>
<th colspan="2">{{$customer_data->name}}i</th>
<th colspan="1">Customer Tax No</th>
<th colspan="2">{{$customer_data->tax_no}}</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>

 <table class="table table-bordered" style="text-align:center;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>S</th>
                    <th>Item Code</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Unit</th>
                    <th>Unit Price</th>
                    <th>Qty</th>
                    <th>Amount($)
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                @foreach($product_sale_data as $key=>$product_sale_data)
                @php
          $product_data = \App\Product::find($product_sale_data->product_id);
                    if($product_data->sale_unit_id)
      $unit = \App\Unit::find($product_data->sale_unit_id)->unit_name;
                    else
                        $unit = 'N/A';
                @endphp  
    <tr class =  @if  ( $key % 22 == 0 && $key ) "page-break"   @endif>
 <td>{{$key+1}}</td>
  <td>{{$product_data->code}}</td>
  <td>{{$product_data->name}}</td>
 <td>{{$unit}}</td>
<td>{{number_format($product_sale_data->total / $product_sale_data->qty, 2)}}</td>
                    <td>{{$product_sale_data->qty}}</td>
                    <td>{{number_format($product_sale_data->total, 2)}}</td>
                @endforeach
                 <br>
```

Comment: the page-* selectors are not fully implemented and have various levels of support across the browsers (https://caniuse.com/#search=page-break). There is nothing that you can do but wait for the browsers to catch up with their support.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: If `$key` value start with 0 then below `<thead>` is not need but if `$key` starts with 1 then below is needed for one time no need to loop in `foreach`

```
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>S</th>
            <th>Item Code</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Unit</th>
            <th>Unit Price</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Amount($)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    @foreach($product_sale_data as $key=>$product_sale_data)
        @if  ( $key % 22 == 0 && $key ) // so here every 22 rows after this will go
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>S</th>
                    <th>Item Code</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Unit</th>
                    <th>Unit Price</th>
                    <th>Qty</th>
                    <th>Amount($)
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        @endif
        <tbody> 
            @php
            $product_data = \App\Product::find($product_sale_data->product_id);
                if($product_data->sale_unit_id)

            ...continue your code
```

Comment: thank you, but I need to repeat this table in any new page

<table class="table hed">
<thead style="text-align:center;">
<tr style="text-align:center;">  
    <th colspan="1">Name</th>
<th colspan="2">{{$customer_data->name}}i</th>
<th colspan="1">Customer Tax No</th>
<th colspan="2">{{$customer_data->tax_no}}</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>